# PowerShell XML Copy Node within same file

Tags: xml, powershell

I am tying to copy the xml node within the same file but I am getting the error.
Please check.

PowerShell Script:

```
$path=".."
cd $path
[xml]$xdoc = Get-Content $path
$NodeToClone = $xdoc.root.Version.Version.Builds.Build.Clone()
$xdoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild($NodeToClone)
$xdoc.Save($path)
```

XML file:

```
<root>
  <Versions>
    <Version Number="3">
      <Builds>
        <Build Number="205" Version="30">
          <Steps>
            <Step Number="1" Build="205" Version="3">
              <SubSteps>
                <SubStep Number="1" comment="" />
              </SubSteps>
            </Step>
            <Step Number="2" Build="205" Version="3">
              <SubSteps>
                <SubStep Number="1" Path="" File="" Action="" CSV_Type="" cq_number="" continue_on_error="" comment="" />
                <SubStep Number="2" Path="" File="" Action="" CSV_Type="" cq_number="" continue_on_error="" comment="" />
                </SubSteps>
            </Step>
            <Step Number="3" Build="205" Version="3">
              <SubSteps>
                <SubStep Number="1" comment="" />
              </SubSteps>
            </Step>
          </Steps>
        </Build>
      </Builds>
    </Version>
  </Versions>
</root>
```

I want to copy the build node for next number 206, but I am getting the below error:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>       At D:\Powershell-MyScripts\test.ps1:6 char:48
>       + $NodeToClone = $xdoc.root.Version.Version.Clone <<<< ()
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Clone:String) [], RuntimeException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> Exception calling "AppendChild" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
>       At D:\Powershell-MyScripts\test.ps1:7 char:34
>       + $xdoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild <<<< ($NodeToClone)
>           + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a 's' in your XML path (...Version.Version... instead of ...Versions.Version...)

```
$NodeToClone = $xdoc.root.Versions.Version.Builds.Build.Clone()
```

In addition you probably want to change the node to append your cloned node to

```
$xdoc.root.Versions.Version.Builds.AppendChild($NodeToClone)
```

Otherwise it is not on the same level as your previous node.

**Update after discussion in comments:**

```
[xml]$xdoc = Get-Content $path
$NodeToClone = @($xdoc.root.Versions.Version.Builds.Build)[-1].Clone()  

$NodeToClone.Number = ([int]($NodeToClone.Number) + 1).ToString()
foreach ($step in $NodeToClone.Steps.Step) {
    $step.Build = $NodeToClone.Number   
}  

$xdoc.root.Versions.Version.Builds.AppendChild($NodeToClone)
$xdoc.Save($path)
```

Comment: Thanks, But now it is copying the node three times on running the code  one time.

Comment: Well I think it is not quite clear what node you want to be copied. Is it the "Build" node or one of its children, i.e "Step" nodes? Currently the code will copy the "Build" node which results in 3 additional "Step" nodes ...

Comment: The whole Build node with incremented value of number. Like 205, then next node 206 and so on... But it is copying the node three times which must not happen. It must be one time on single run of code.

Comment: Have a look to the updated answer if this works for you. BTW: The previous code did NOT copy your node 3 times, so I assume you ran the script several times but did not reset the initial XML file which you update in-place.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It works. If you don't mind can you advise me from where I learn Powershell so that I can solve such problem on my own..

Comment: Well PowerShell is really well documented so I know this is probably not the answer you are looking for but: just start to use it everyday. Use "help %some_command% -Full" if you use a command or one of its parameters you are not familiar with and automate repetitive tasks of your workday with PowerShell. If you are really completely new then as a starting point you could read the fundamental concepts at  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/fundamental-concepts. From there IMHO the best way to learn is use it :)

Comment: Thanks @DAZaholic.. It works and I accepted it. Like you say , I have tried and want to increment the Build=205 also which comes under Step element. For this I run command, "$NodeToClone.Steps.Step.build = ([int]($NodeToClone.steps.step.Build) + 1).ToString()" BUT it not converting it. Am I doing wrong anything here ?

Comment: @DAZaholic.. PLease help

Comment: I have updated the answer. The problem in your code is that "$NodeToClone.Steps.Step" refers to an array of nodes which does not allow direct assignment to a property of its elements (but it allows reading a property in case you are curios). BTW: You still did not accept my answer but upvoted it - to accept it you have to enable the green checkmark :)

Comment: Thanks and Sorry I was not aware of green checkmark, But now I done it.